# NHibernate: mapping for complex object with interfaces for single table

Tags: c#, nhibernate, mapping, legacy, fluent

I am trying to map a composite object that has a property with an interface (INameTypeInfo). This interface is implemented by 2 classes (PersonNameInfo and CompanyNameInfo).  The information for all three of these structures in the same table.

**The object looks like this:**

```
public class Name : Entity
{
    public virtual string FirstName {get; set;}

    public virtual string LastName {get; set;}

    public virtual INameTypeInfo NameTypeInfo {get; set;}

    etc...
}
```

**The other objects look like this:**

```
public class PersonNameTypeInfo()
{
    public string SSN {get; set;}
    public string AKAFistName {get; set;}
    public string AKALastName {get; set;}
    etc...
}

public class CompanyNameTypeInfo()
{
    public string FederalIDNumber {get; set;}
    public string AKAName {get; set;}
    etc...
}
```

**The db table looks like this:**

Names

- FirstName
- LastName
- AKAFistName <------When the information is for a company, this field is used for AKAName
- AKALastName
- SSN
- FID
- CompanyContact

Also note:  The Name object is also inherited by other objects, like Party:Name, Provider:Name, etc...

The database is a legacy db that is already in use.

Any example of how I could map this with fluent would be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: hmm from what I've always done is just do company and then that gives you access to ehw hole company object, Hibernate is cascading...

Comment: Not following you Kevin.  Are you saying just map CompanyNameTypeInfo?

Comment: yeah, that's what I always do i'll write an example.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class person
{

// this is the table for person 
   private String name;
   private String lastName;
   private Company company;


}


public class Company
{ 
  private string name;
  private string address;
  // more properties.
}
```

when you load th persons, then you also can use the company. So when you say
Person.company.name it will get the name, and if you change anything within the person that deals with company Hibernate cascades all the changes when you commit it back to the database.

Maybe thats not you question, but just a food for thought.

but if you want to make them a composite key you can make a third object example

```
public class  organization
{
  private person person;
  private company company;
}
```

rather than having company inside a person. when you retrieve organization you get both person and company DAO